# Need help cracking a SHA256 hash, based on a list of hint strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, sha256, password-hash

I tried asking this question on security.stackexchange, but it was marked as off-topic. So I figured it probably would fit more in on here. Here goes:

I have just begun my bachelor's in IT security and we have been presented with a list of exercises. I have completed all, but one of them. (Note: this is to be done in Python).

In this exercise we are given a SHA256 hash, which is a user's password, and a list of "hint" strings, based on personal information from social media, for the particular user.

We are told that the password will be of length 8 and to use these hint strings, to crack the hash.

I am by no means an expert in Python, but I do know quite a fair share. However, I believe I could use a little help or a nudge in the right direction.

So, to make it short and simple, here is the available info I've been given:

- Password length: 8
- Password hash (SHA256): 0ba128bd856006948e7c57b714586bf43199aa898cc2bcd25141d951a34664a8
- List of hint strings: [("Lars","Hansen","05","09","1984"),("fido"),("jan","08","08","2014"),("barcelona","fodbold")])
- Language: Python

I would assume that this task is made so that we're supposed to grab parts of the different strings and mix them, hash the combined string and then compare to the known hash.

So far, I have not had any luck.

Things I have tried:

I have tried a bunch of different options, mostly using functions from the itertools module, which I then hash with hashlib's sha256 function and then compare the hashes.
I have used the product function, the permutations function and the combinations function.
I have tried using the first two characters in each string tuple.
I also (pretty stupid I know) tried to brute-force it using all ascii letters and digits.. But that would take forever.

---

CODE:

Here is the code that I've been trying:

```py
import itertools as it
import hashlib as hlib

data = (("0ba128bd856006948e7c57b714586bf43199aa898cc2bcd25141d951a34664a8"),[("Lars","Hansen","05","09","1984"),("fido"),("jan","08","08","2014"),("barcelona","fodbold")])

sha256 = data[0]
user_info = data[1]


chain_info = it.chain(user_info).from_iterable(user_info)
info_list = list(chain_info)

info_array = []

for i in info_list:
    if len(i) > 1:
        info_array.append(i[0:2])
    else:
        info_array.append(i)

info_array[10] = "fi"
info_array[11] = "do"

info_array.remove("d")
info_array.remove("o")

prod = it.product(info_array, repeat=4) #repeat = 4 since I use two letter combinations.


for i in prod:
    hashed = hlib.sha256("".join(i).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
    if hashed == sha256:
        print("".join(i))
        break
```

Comment: _I have tried a bunch of different options_, please share your code.

Comment: Will; the resulting password use the capitalization case of the hints or do you also need to take different letter cases?  Does the password have to comply with strict rules such as 'at least 1 capital letter, 1 number", etc.  Will hint words be scrambled when building the password?  If you don't know the answer you would have to take the list of hint words, convert to a string of letters, take the string of letters 8 at a time, then for each case Capitalize the letters,  shuffle the letter combinations and run a sha256 hash on the series and compare to target.

Comment: @Maurice Meyer I have added the code.

Comment: It could be that the password combines the hints in some way other than 2 characters from each of 4 words. Also, perhaps common character substitutions are involved ("f1d0", "b@rce10n@" etc).

Comment: @itprorh66 The resulting password might use another capitalization case than the hints, so yes, I might need to take different letter cases. The password is said to include both uppercase, lowercase letters and number(s), so there has to be atleast one of each. I do know not for sure if the hint words will be scrambled, but I am under the impression that they will not be, since it is supposed to be a "simple" user password that is easy to remember. So in this case, the password would probably follow the structure like: LaFi84ba or something similar to that.

Comment: @slothrop That is true, good point. As far as I can tell, no symbols are included, but letters and digits might be switched. And yes, it could very well be that I have to combine the hints in other ways than 2 characters from each tuple/different string.

Comment: Small point, but if you want to avoid the complexity that "fido" is a single string while the other elements of `user_info` are tuples, then you could replace `("fido")` with `("fido",)`

Comment: @slothrop Aah, thank you. I had been thinking about the best way to solve that, just never got around to do it. That is a way better way, thanks :)

Comment: @itprorh66 and slothrop-- Thank you both for your comments, I have now solved the problem, after some time thinking and then some changes to my code. Your comments made me think about other ways/new ways to solve this, which resulted in me getting the answer eventually. Have a great day, to the both of you.

Comment: @slothrop -- I couldn't tag you in my previous comment, but I'm tagging you here, to let you know that I have now solved the problem and to thank you for your comments :) Have a great day :)

Comment: Do not edit your question with the solution. Instead, add an answer to your question.